# how to assign target control to validator control on serverside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, target, validation

I am having N numbers of Text boxes those are generating dynamically. I want to validate each textbox for Formate HH:MM:SS PM/AM so i dynamicaly create the validation control . but as the dynamic textbox has no ID , so what i have to pass to the Validation control for ControlToValidate Property ?

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? (Winforms/Gtk/Qt/Cocoa or just HTML or validate on server side... all affects the result.)

Comment: Dear Lalit, Why your textboxes has no ID. it is not important that they will generate autmatically, but Why they shouldn't have ID?
---- anyway, Users browser will generate an ID for your textboxes, justright click on the web page and view page source. then find out that whats the textbox ID(s) and use it.

Comment: .Net framework 3.5 . It is pure asp.net page.

Comment: Nasser Hajloo so what should have to give the targetcontrolid of validator control. I m not getting any ID of textbox

Comment: dear friend Nasser Hajloo, This is wrong way ... which will not work... I want to assign the Target id .. see below i sending code , which is not working

Comment: Users browser will generate an ID for your textboxes, justright click on the web page and view page source. then find out that whats the textbox ID(s) and use it

Answer (score 0):

AccordionPane ap1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                ap1 = new AccordionPane();
                ap1.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Using Markup"));
                Panel pnl = new Panel();

```
                TextBox txtTime = new TextBox();
                txtTime.ID = "txtTimeBox" + i;
                txtTime.ValidationGroup = "MKE";
                RegularExpressionValidator validateDate = new RegularExpressionValidator();
                validateDate.ValidationExpression = "(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|60) (AM|PM|am|pm)";
                validateDate.ControlToValidate = txtTime.ID;
                validateDate.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date. Try in HH:MM:SS AM/am|PM/pm format";

                pnl.Controls.Add(txtTime);
                ap1.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(pnl);
            MyAccordion.Panes.Add(ap1);
        }
        Page.Controls.Add(divContainer);
```

Comment: this is my code. in dynamic N number of accordian ther are texboxes...those i want validate